# Gets unauthorized error when I send correctly token

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I work with Web API and Angular 8.
I try to secure my server-side but then I get unauthorized error
for every token I send.

I tried to look for a solution on the internet but I didn't find anything.

That is my code

C#:

```
public string GenerateTokenForUser(UsersDTO user)
    {
        var signingKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(signingKey));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, 
        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.id.ToString())
        }, "custom");
        var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
        {
            Issuer = "self",
            Subject = claimsIdentity,
            SigningCredentials = creds,
            Expires = now.AddHours(5)
        };
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var plainToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
    var signedAndEncodedToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(plainToken);
    return signedAndEncodedToken;
}
```

Web API:

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("GetLearnedPagesCount/{userId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetLearnedPagesCount(int userId)
    {
      ...
    }
```

Angular:

```
httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': `Bearer `+this.cookieService.get('token')
  })
};

 GetLearnedPages(): Observable<Array<MyPages>> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Array<MyPages>>(this.serverServ.URL + "Controller/GetLearnedPages/" 
    + this.user.id, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

I get a correct token and I get it from the cookies too.

What can be my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Do not forget to change the signing key after you post it publicly...